# How to decrypt a file that was encrypted before?

Tags: python, cryptography

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher = Fernet(key)


def encrypt_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
    encrypted_content = cipher.encrypt(content)
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(encrypted_content)


encrypt_file(file_path)


def decrypt_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        encrypted_content = f.read()
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        decrypted_content = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_content)
        f.write(decrypted_content)


decrypt_file(file_path)
```

I'm new on cryptography so I wonder how can I decrypt a file that was encrypted before? Do I need to use my key to encrypt content of a file?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's the problem? Also, please read about creating a [mre].

Comment: *...Do I need to use my key to encrypt content of a file?...* Fernet requires a key for encryption and the *same* key for decryption. Take a look at [Symmetric-key algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) (which also includes [Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#fernet-spec)).

Comment: @bereal my code works fine if I run the encrypt and decrypt functions at the same time. but I want to just do encryption. For example I'm running just encrypt function firstly. It doing the encryption fine and changing its content with encrypted version. then I'm running the code second time with just decryption function for decrypt it. but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: If you run the posted code, a new key is generated *each time* (by `generateKey()`). If you perform encryption and decryption *together*, the *same* key is used and the decryption is successful. If you perform both *separately*, *different* keys are used and decryption fails.

Comment: Your code is missing the part that stores (or outputs) the key generated during encryption somewhere so that it can be reused during decryption. If your question now is whether you can decrypt the encrypted file without a key: No, not with modern algorithms (like AES, which is used by Fernet). That is precisely the purpose of encryption, see e.g. [*How long would it take to brute force an AES-128 key?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48667).

Comment: @NotARobot thank you very much finally I fixed it. I couldn't realize that the code generates a new key every time :D

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between encryption and decryption is the use of the appropriate function from the Fernet class.

You need to start your program with an input file that contains unencrypted data. After that you can encrypt and decrypt from the same file then check that its contents match the original.

Something like this:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def process(filename, op, debug=False):
    # open file for read/write (binary)
    with open(filename, "rb+") as data:
        # decrypt/encrypt according to the operation passed to this function
        pdata = op(data.read())
        if debug:
            print(pdata)
        # seek to BOF
        data.seek(0)
        data.write(pdata)
        # important if new output is shorter than original - otherwise benign
        data.truncate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "efile.txt"
    # create an original plain text file
    with open(filename, "w") as original:
        original.write("Hello world!")
    # instantiate Fernet instance
    cipher = Fernet(Fernet.generate_key())
    # encrypt the content
    process(filename, cipher.encrypt, True)
    # decrypt the content
    process(filename, cipher.decrypt)
    # open the original file and check its contents
    with open(filename, "r") as original:
        print(original.read())
```

**Example output:**

```
b'gAAAAABlip7aSoPRMxXE6kFNywvhAyKN-RX083fSHKO1GakcrbhUjtvcm1TtGOe1UGUlnfUoSAm7xoDfgTpQkanRMsNIumaRyg=='
Hello world!
```

**EDIT:**

Given that the generated key needs to be known at both encryption and decryption phases you could consider serialising the Fernet instance. Of course, this offers little or no security.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from pickle import load, dump
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def load_cipher(pkl):
    pkl.seek(0)
    return load(pkl)

def process(filename, pickle_file, action):
    cipher = load_cipher(pickle_file)
    with open(filename, "rb+") as data:
        pdata = getattr(cipher, action)(data.read())
        data.seek(0)
        data.write(pdata)
        data.truncate()

def create(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as original:
        original.write("Hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "efile.txt"
    # create an original plain text file
    create(filename)
    # generate Fernet instance and serialise (pickle) it
    with TemporaryFile() as pickle_file:
        dump(Fernet(Fernet.generate_key()), pickle_file)
        # encrypt the content
        process(filename, pickle_file, "encrypt")
        # decrypt the content
        process(filename, pickle_file, "decrypt")
        # open the original file and check its contents
        with open(filename, "r") as original:
            print(original.read())
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I guess I couldn't explain my problem properly. my goal is decrypt a file that was encrypted at another time. for example in your code when I first do just the encryption then run it again with just decryption it didn't work. first I'm getting this error: "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" then it says: "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken" (sorry for my bad english by the way)

Comment: In this example, the generated key is known both at encryption and decryption phases. You cannot decrypt the file unless you know the key that was used to encrypt it. That's the whole point of this particular encryption mechanism